# Rename populate returned values Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to return returned properties, much like in `Mysql`'s `AS`. But with renamed object properties.

**Query**

```
Games.find({leagueID:leagueID, result:{$ne: null}}).populate('home_id away_id').sort({date: -1}).execAsync()
```

**Output**

```
{
    home_id: {
        ...some details
    },
    away_id: {
        ...some details
    }
}
```

**Desired Output**

```
{
    home: {
        ...some details
    },
    away: {
        ...some details
    }
}
```

So how can I get the desired outcome?

Comment: How about just caliing them "home" and "away" to begin with since your only intent seems to be to populate that with the related object. Otherwise you basically need to convert the mongoose documents returned to standard objects, create new keys, copy data, then remove old keys. Seems that just naminng them what you want is the most logical thing to do for your end result.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to use the transform function.

```
GamesSchema.set('toJSON', {
    transform: function(doc, ret, options) {   
        if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(ret.home)) {
            ret.homeId = ret.home;
            delete ret.home;
        }
        if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(ret.away)) {
            ret.awayId = ret.away;
            delete ret.away;
        }
    }
});
```

**Without populate:**

Input

```
{
    "_id": "sD95OhsGrWVIqmTLVeuQdkna",
    "leagueID": 1000,
    "home": "404d1d9f68c3bb386b50f440" // ObjectId
    "away": "504d1d9f68c3bb386b50f450" // ObjectId
}
```

Output

```
{
    "_id": "sD95OhsGrWVIqmTLVeuQdkna",
    "leagueID": 1000,
    "homeId": "404d1d9f68c3bb386b50f440"
    "awayId": "504d1d9f68c3bb386b50f450"
}
```

**With populate:**

Input

```
{
    "_id": "sD95OhsGrWVIqmTLVeuQdkna",
    "leagueID": 1000,
    "home": "404d1d9f68c3bb386b50f440" // ObjectId
    "away": "504d1d9f68c3bb386b50f450" // ObjectId
}
```

Output

```
{
    "_id": "sD95OhsGrWVIqmTLVeuQdkna",
    "leagueID": 1000,
    "home": {
        "_id": "404d1d9f68c3bb386b50f440",
        "name": "Home"
    }
    "away": {
        "_id": "504d1d9f68c3bb386b50f450",
        "name": "Away"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and manipulate the output field like this

`db.collection.aggregate([{ $project:{_id:0, home:"$home_id", away:"$away_id"} }])`

Comment: I like where this is going Rohit :) But how can i use this in my example

Comment: Can you share the sample document or you can try the "$match" follow by the "$project"

Answer (score 0):

Try lodash's _.mapKeys, like this:

```
const newObject = _.mapKeys(oldObject.toJSON(), (value, key) => {
            if (key === 'oldKey') return 'newKey';
            return key;
          });
```